# Comprimir y descomprimir una cadena [avanzado]

Tags: c#, bitconverter

Buen día.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Tengo el siguiente script que me pasaron

```
string compressedWalletID = "stZYb4GtpEiSXLeL8XskGZrDyQE=";
 

//convert from base64 to byte array
var walletBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedWalletID);

 
//the first 16 bytes contains the Onecard client ID guid
Guid clientID = new Guid(walletBytes.Take(16).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("Client ID: " + clientID.ToString());
 

//the next four bytes contains the Onecard wallet number
int walletNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(walletBytes, 16);
Console.WriteLine("Wallet number: " + walletNumber.ToString());


//and going in reverse, here's how to encode it back into a compressed wallet number as stored in the customer profile
compressedWalletID = Convert.ToBase64String(clientID.ToByteArray().Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(walletNumber)).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine("Compressed wallet ID: " + compressedWalletID); 


The output from the above code is:
Client ID: 6f58d6b2-ad81-48a4-925c-b78bf17b2419
Wallet number: 30000026
Compressed wallet ID: stZYb4GtpEiSXLeL8XskGZrDyQE=
```

Lo que yo busco es que el usuario pueda ingresar el **ClientID** y **WalletNumber** Para poder comprimir la cadena, pero cuando lo hago en programa truena, me dice que tengo errores de typos.

**Para comprimir se usa esta línea**

```
compressedWalletID = Convert.ToBase64String(clientID.ToByteArray().Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(walletNumber)).ToArray());
```

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora, el descomprimir ya lo tengo me falta el comprimir

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
  public void compress() {
    string clientIDConst = "6f58d6b2-ad81-48a4-925c-b78bf17b2419";
    int walletNumberConst = 30000026;

    string clientID = "";
    string walletNumber;

    string compressedWalletID = "";

    Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    Console.Write("Ingrese el Client ID: ");
    clientID = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Ingrese el Wallet number: ");
    walletNumber = Console.ReadLine();

    // aqui se realiza la compresión
    // compressedWalletID = Convert.ToBase64String(clientID.ToByteArray().Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(walletNumber)).ToArray()); 
    // Console.WriteLine("Compressed walletNumber: " + clientID.ToByteArray());     

  }

  public void uncompress() {

    string compressedWalletID = "";
    Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
    Console.Write("Ingrese el compressedWalletID: ");
    compressedWalletID = Console.ReadLine();

    var walletBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedWalletID);

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("======= Descompreción correcta ===========");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    //the first 16 bytes contains the Onecard client ID guid
    Guid clientID = new Guid(walletBytes.Take(16).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Client ID: " + clientID.ToString());

    //the next four bytes contains the Onecard wallet number
    int walletNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(walletBytes, 16);
    Console.WriteLine("Wallet number: " + walletNumber.ToString());
  }

  public void question(int nmb) {
    Program pr = new Program();
    string number;
    switch (nmb) {
    case 1:
      pr.compress();
      break;
    case 2:
      pr.uncompress();
      break;
    default:
      number = "Error";
      break;
    }

  }

  public static void Main() {

    int opt;
    Console.WriteLine("******** ¿Qué desea hacer? ********");

    Console.WriteLine("1: Descomprimir WalletID ");
    Console.WriteLine("2: Generar WalletID comprimido");

    Console.Write("Seleccione la opcion deseada: ");
    opt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Program pr = new Program();
    pr.question(opt);

  }
}
```

Soy nuevo en C# y esos tipos de conversiones son muy avanzadas para mi aunque me hayan pasado el primer programa de referencia.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: base64 no comprime y yo diría que hasta hace lo contrario, te entrega algo más grande.  Entonces, tú quieres comprimir o mostrar la concatenación de las 2 entradas en base64???

Comment: Exacto justo eso quiero, mostrar la concatenacion en base64, pero cuando lo hago me da errores de typos, y la verdad no sé como convertirlos @Yussef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así quedaría el código

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Descomprimido = decompress("stZYb4GtpEiSXLeL8XskGZrDyQE=");
        Console.WriteLine(Descomprimido.walletNumber);
        Console.WriteLine(Descomprimido.clientID);

        var comprimido = compress("6f58d6b2-ad81-48a4-925c-b78bf17b2419", 30000026);
        Console.WriteLine(comprimido);
    }
    public static (Guid clientID, int walletNumber) decompress(string compressedWalletID)
    {
        var walletBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedWalletID);
        return (new Guid(walletBytes.Take(16).ToArray()), BitConverter.ToInt32(walletBytes, 16));
    }


    public static string compress(string clientID, int walletNumber)
        => compress(new Guid(clientID), walletNumber);
    public static string compress(Guid clientID, int walletNumber)
        => Convert.ToBase64String(clientID.ToByteArray().Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(walletNumber)).ToArray()); 
}
```

Comment: Hola @Yussef gracias por tu respuesta, en el ejemplo que me dan la salida de compress debería ser esta: Compressed wallet ID: stZYb4GtpEiSXLeL8XskGZrDyQE= y en tu ejemplo me da una cadena mucho más grande "NmY1OGQ2YjItYWQ4MS00OGE0LTkyNWMtYjc4YmYxN2IyNDE5msPJAQ==", sabes ¿En que influye esto?

Comment: @ManueelPerezz Es que no entendí la pregunta. Ahora va el código que creo es lo que quieres. Recuerda que si la respuesta ha sido correcta puedes marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Sos el mejor @Yussef Exactamente eso es lo que necesitaba, Wow.